# Platform game: applying gravity and jumping

Tags: java, physics, platformer

I am making a 2D platform game in Java but I don't know how to apply gravity and jumping on my player and other living creatures in game that it looks natural and that it is physical correct.
I have formula: speed = v0 + gt^2/2
but i don't know how to implement it in my code...

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The top answer from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702412/variable-timestep-and-acceleration) shows how to update position and velocity using the equations of motion. Although that particular question is related to some ship, the formula is the same for jumping.

Comment: Don't forget to search before posting:  http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2799/good-2d-platformer-physics  as well as https://www.google.com/search?q=2d+jumping+physics